# Removing NaNs from dictionary - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the NaNs from my dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'House': ['has keys',
  'check lights',
  nan,
  nan,
  nan],
 'The Office': ['reading',
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  'coffee breaks']}
```

I believe the NaNs are floats, not strings. I have tried:

```
import math

my_dict['House'] = [
    x
    for x in dict2['House']
    if not (isinstance(x, float) and math.isnan(x))
]
```

And I get:

```
my_dict = {'House': ['has keys',
  'check lights',],
 'The Office': ['reading',
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  'coffee breaks']}
```

I would like it to look like the following, but I dont know how to get my for loop to loop through all keys instead of just House:

```
my_dict = {'House': ['has keys',
  'check lights'],
 'The Office': ['reading',
  'coffee breaks']}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `pandas` tag here? Is this data stored in a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @Erfan yes, it is stored in a pandas dataframe. I can try to remove the tag if it does not relate to pandas!

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it'll filter all the values in the dictionary, removing NaN numbers:

```
{ k: [x for x in v if not isinstance(x, float) or not math.isnan(x)] for k, v in my_dict.items() }
```

This is the result:

```
{'House': ['has keys', 'check lights'],
 'The Office': ['reading', 'coffee breaks']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged `pandas`, you can do something like:

```
print(df)
```

---

```
          House     The Office
0      has keys        reading
1  check lights            NaN
2           NaN            NaN
3           NaN            NaN
4           NaN  coffee breaks
```

---

```
df_new=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print(df_new)
```

---

```
          House     The Office
0      has keys        reading
1  check lights  coffee breaks
```

Answer (score 0):

you are on the correct track, but you only check 'house', you need to apply your logic to all your keys:

```
import math
for tv_show in my_dict:
    my_dict[tv_show] = [
        x
        for x in dict2[tv_show]
        if not (isinstance(x, float) and math.isnan(x))
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go the other way around and only retain string values (as long as you ONLY want string values, of course):

```
>>> for k, v in my_dict.items():
>>>     my_dict[k] = [val for val in v if isinstance(val, str)]

>>> my_dict
# {'House': ['has keys', 'check lights'], 'The Office': ['reading', 'coffee breaks']}
```

Even though this can also be achieved in a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), I think the logic is a bit dense in this case for a one-liner, however, it would look like this:

```
>>> {k: [val for val in v if isinstance(val, str)] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```